# What would you call the occupation of a person who changes vacuum tubes?

Tags: vacuum-tube

As the title states, what would be the job title of a vacuum tube replacer? Vacuum tube operator? Vacuum tube engineer? If your job had you spending most of your time replacing vacuum tubes, what would you put on your resume?

I'm assuming this was an actual job during the vacuum tube computing days, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Would it have been a job by itself or would it have just been one of several duties for a computer technician?

Comment: The ENIAC had what I would consider a high rate of tube failure - one every 2 days (per wikipedia).  It hardly seems like a full-time job.  My understanding was that Eckert's approach of undervolting tubes, coupled with burn-in before use,  sigificantly increased reliability.  Subsequent stored-program machines had lower valve counts.

Comment: The job, rather, is one of "keeping the computer working".  In the build-it-yourself computing era, presumably this job fell to technical staff.  Even when you could buy a computer, and even into the transistor era, it was usual for vendor support engineers ('field engineers' or 'customer engineers') to have the machine for a few hours a day or, later, a week, for "preventive maintenance". The vendor staff probably even had on-site office space.

Comment: Vtuber, obviously.

Comment: @user3840170 [Ouch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_YouTuber) :))

Comment: @Raffzahn We don't talk about those.

Comment: @HashimAziz We don't talk about [Bruno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvWRMAU6V-c)?

Comment: @another-dave replacing a tube is rather quick, but searching for a failed tube in a 20000-tube computer may be quite an engagement.

Comment: Surely the name should have been 'vacuum cleaner'

Answer (score 20):

> What would you call the occupation of a person who changes vacuum tubes?

Nothing specific, as it's not a job in itself, but the part of the tasks a

- **Customer Engineer**
- **Maintenance Engineer**,
- **Field Engineer**, or
- **Service Engineer**

would do. Naming choice may vary according to company - likewise some used the term **Technician** instead of **Engineer**. They were almost exclusive employed by the machines manufacturers service division. Maybe except for the very first one off machines build at some university.

---

Being trained in that job, in the late 1970s, I got a title of **Service Technician** (German: Wartungstechniker).

Comment: According to one of the KDF9 brochures, English Electric used the term "resident engineer".  I don't know if this was a mandatory peripheral with every computer, or if there was a timesharing option.

Comment: @another-dave Now that's a nice term. Can't really talk about English Electric, but we had back then a default location to show up in the morning, but after that being time shared all over the city :))

Comment: Don't forget, "T.V. Repairman." Once was a time when every town in the U.S.A. had at least one T.V. repair shop.

Comment: Remember there was a time - not too long ago, really - where every airplane flew with an "engineer" on board to make sure the engines kept running properly - or even at all!  Earlier than that - every race car in a race ran with its own mechanic on board - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plRfCsfzG-g - the early scenes clearly show _two heads_ popping up in each car!  One: the driver.  Two: the mechanic!

Comment: Even today, a Chief Engineer for an AM radio station is likely to replace a tube from time to time.

Comment: As a Navy sonar technician, I had to replace a lot of tubes.  Some of them because a supposedly trained technician would double the filament voltage on the tube tester to "check for borderline conditions."  SMH  Some because a fathometer was built with a clamp mounted wrong, so every time a new tube was clamped in, it punctured the glass (the glue in the base kept it from making a sound).

Comment: Well, this surprises me, _a lot!_ Should there really be no colloquialism, slang term, from either private sector, specialists, 'insiders', internal communications, the military, geeks & nerds? Did you & your colleagues not call yourself by mock-terms, (mock) insults or derogatory epithets? Not even technical origin abbreviations for eg Wartungstechniker? Like: WaTech->Watt-Echsen,  maybe Birnenschubse(r), Strippenzeieher, Drahtschrauber, or sth? Was it really that dry, even informally?

Comment: @LаngLаngС Oh, no, we were the elite - but we had of course names for other groups, like Quadratkupfermechaniker for mains/power technicians. Druckerputzer (printer cleaner) was a rather indirect naming, more in form of a thread to send someone Druckerputzen. Helpful to remember that drum/chain printers (the real ones, not that puny stuff using pin heads) created a lot of paper dust and needed cleaning every few days of running - and they were running 24/7 at large installations. Ever been to a room with a dozend of them in full action?

Comment: Nah, have not, but I'd _love_ to see that (hear?), at least a vid! / "The Elite", 'called others', I have little trouble to accept—So: you called _others_ names… ;) (whether in good fun or other spirits I don't care), then the question immediately becomes: what did _they_ call _your lot?_ Really always full-time official lingo? If you still have contacts: I'd guess that's well worth a round of q&a, war time stories?

Comment: @LаngLаngС Since when does the upper class even recognise others worth of being differentiated? :)) But no, sorry to disappoint you, there wasn't much name calling. It was a rather professional environment based on knowledge. I still remember one colleague who was on of the best disk technicians I ever met - although I think he was rather a musician by heart, playing the trombone in an orchestra and driving an Alpha Spider - with a boot to small to take a disk motor even without its crate. But its a different story how we managed to transport on at night n a weekend to a customer site.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Take [this 1403](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiEGoVzmyvs) printer and imagine a device 20 years later, up to twice the speed (guess noise gets up quadratic), and a dozend of them working in parallel.  Like a CDC 585 doing  a peak of 2000 lines a minute - that's a >30 line printed per second, a page every 2 seconds and a sound vibrating around C1/Cis1 :))  Also: http://www.righto.com/2019/09/risky-line-printer-music-on-vintage-ibm.html

Comment: Oh wow! I thought "risky" meant ["Schalter C ist verboten"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtlrITxB5qg), but this opens up really previously unheard, and when categorized by timeline _much_ later possibilities/practises. When I personally first sampled these 'industrial noises' (floppy & pin needles) or heard them in _complex_ coordinated action (post YouTube era hacks), it was all so much later… Thanks, inspiring!

Comment: @LаngLаngС Nice :)) I remember those. I think I still have somewhere a whole tape with prints. Speaking of industrial noise, I remember a program for a 4004/45 (more or less a Spectra 70/45) playing music on (I think) AM radio.